# How do I create a Custom Client Authenticator in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to set up a custom client authenticator in WSO2 Identity Server, I would like to retrieve an access token with client_credentials specifying a specific scope and have a jwt token returned with custom claims inserted. I've tried writing my own Client Authenticator but I'm having some trouble getting the OSGi bundle to pick up correctly during WSO2 startup and all other attempts at customizing the auth flow have failed.
Is there anyone who would be able to point me in the right direction as to where I might find useful information on how to achieve what I'm trying to achieve? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Using WSO2 Identity Server, you are able to extend the client authentication implementation. You can write your own client authentication mechanism following a specification or any other standard.
Please follow the below doc link to create the custom client Authenticator:
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/writing-a-new-oauth-client-authenticator/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).